# Trying to Duplicate Existing C# TripleDES Encryption Code Into Javascript/Typescript

Tags: c#, typescript, encryption, tripledes

So we currently have a TripleDES encryption code in C# that looks like this:

```
static byte[] KEY_192 = {bunch of random comma-delimited numbers};
static byte[] IV_192 = {different bunch of random comma-delimited numbers};

public static string EncryptTripleDES(string sValue)
{
    string sEncryptedValue = "";
    if (sValue.Length > 0)
    {
        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider cryptoProvider = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, cryptoProvider.CreateEncryptor(KEY_192, IV_192), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(cs);

        sw.Write(sValue);
        sw.Flush();
        cs.FlushFinalBlock();
        ms.Flush();

        //convert back to a string
        sEncryptedValue = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, Convert.ToInt32(ms.Length));
    }

    return sEncryptedValue;
}
```

Which has worked fine for us. But now we're moving over to Angular which requires us to recreate this method in Typescript/Javascript. To that end I'm using CryptoJS and my current code is as follows:

```
private arrKey: number[] = [same bunch of random numbers as in the C# code];
private arrIV: number[] = [same bunch of random numbers as in the C# code];
private key = this.bin2String(this.arrKey);
private iv = this.bin2String(this.arrIV);

constructor () { }

// Converts array to string
private bin2String(array) {
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(String, array);
}

encryptString(stringToBeEncrypted: string) {
    const encrypted = CryptoJS.TripleDES.encrypt(stringToBeEncrypted, this.key,
    {
        iv: this.iv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });

    return encrypted.toString();
}
```

The problem is that the Typescript/Javascript code result doesn't match the C# result at all. As far as I can tell the key and IV seems to be the same on both sides. It's hard to tell cause converting the byte arrays to string results in gobbledygook that's hard to compare. On the C# side I get:

```
key: cÙ iwCS¬9É›…)½è?¨·
IV: ØU?u-»Ê]Ûg5Éž eRÞ
```

While on the T/Jscript side I get:

```
key: cÙ
iwCS¬9É)½è?¨·
IV: ØU?u-»Ê]Ûg5É
eRÞ
```

But the results are completely different:

```
C#: JJqsQzoGdJBYb4MwQiMFFg==
J/Tscript: U2FsdGVkX1+fTRNAUOEmsjzcTTnMFpUl8dfto0YdqzA=
```

Any idea why the results are completely off? On the C# side of things the default mode and padding settings seem to be the same as what I'm manually setting on CryptoJS.

Comment: TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider is in ECB mode whereas CryptoJS in CBC mode. You need to set `cryptoProvider.IV = iv;`

Comment: I'm fairly certain TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider is set to CBC. At least that's what I'm seeing when I retrieve its mode value. And do I need to specifically set the cryptoProvider.IV? I'm already passing that in on this part of the code:

cryptoProvider.CreateEncryptor(KEY_192, IV_192)

Comment: You should also print the IV and key with base64 to see the equality. You can try to decrypt in C# with  cryptoProvider.IV set.